# Why is this error occrued rancher desktop? (Bridge network did not get an IP address. )

Tags: docker, rancher

Bridge network did not get an IP address.

Using shared network address 192.168.205.2

[image]

Comment: were you able to solve this? Can you please post your findings? I too am looking for this answer.